# How does a computer distinguish whether a binary pattern is an instruction or just a number?

Tags: cpu-architecture, von-neumann

I am reading the book "Computer Organization and Embedded Systems" by Hamacher and my question is: "How does a computer distinguish whether a binary pattern is an instruction or just a number?"

Can anyone help me understand that concept?

Comment: How do you understand whether a letter is a part of a word or just a random letter? Context.

Comment: The letter will make no sense but the word will.

Comment: Think about that...

Comment: For Harvard architecture, Instruction and Data memories are different but what about Von Neumann architecture?

Comment: How does a human distinguish whether `00000100` is an instruction or a number? Instructions *are* numbers. Von Neumann architecture, if you put a number where an instruction is expected it will be treated as an instruction, if you put it where data is expected it will be treated as data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Von Neumann Processor (pretty much any processor out there) can not distinguish between code and data in memory. What ever the instruction pointer of the CPU points to will be loaded into the instruction decoder as an instruction. If it is not a valid instruction it will raise an exception in the CPU.

This enables a program to create new executable code in memory or even change its own code. On the other hand this enables many code injection attacks.

Comment: yup, exactly.  If it decodes as a valid instruction, it runs, even if it isn't a *useful* instruction and e.g. results in a load from a potentially-invalid address.  (Very common if you leave out the `ret` at the bottom of a function in an architecture like x86, where a common padding pattern like `00 00` is a valid instruction (`add [rax], al`).

Answer (score 0):

The way the computer distinguishes between instructions and numbers simply depends on what is reading the data and where. For example, a simple Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU) will include an input for the operation to be done, and two inputs for the operands. The data going into the operand ports is read as numbers, whereas the data going into the operator input is read as an instruction.

It all depends on what computer architecture unit is reading the data, and on what input that unit is reading it.